# I know how to call images by mentioning object manually, but I want to call clicked image into new componet in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

I know how to call images by mentioning object manually, but I want to call clicked image into new componet in vue js.
I tried calling images manually, it worked, but I want to call image into child componet which is clicked on parent component ( Images are dynamic)

```
**Main Component**
<router-link to="" v-for="(image, index) in images" :key="index">
   <div class="imgBox">
       <img v-if="image.name.startsWith('assamese')"
        :src="image.src"
        :alt="image.name"
        v-on:click="goTochild(image.name)"
      />
   </div>
</router-link>

<script>
export default{
 computed: {
        images() {
            const imageContext = require.context(
                "@/assets/images/",
                true,
                /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/
            );
            const images = [];
            imageContext.keys().forEach((src, index) => {
                images.push({
                    id: index,
                    src: imageContext(src),
                    name: src.split("/").pop().split(".")[0],
                });
            });
            return images;
        },
    },
    methods: {
        goTochild(prodId) {
            let imgId = prodId;
            // this.$router.push({ name: "details" });
            this.$router.push({ name: "child", params: { Iid: imgId } });
        },
    },
};
</script>

**Child Component**

<div v-for="(image, index) in images" :key="index">
    <div v-if="imgId == image.id">
     <h1>{{ image.src }}</h1>
     <img width="250" :src="image.src" />
    </div>
</div>

<script>
export default{
 data() {
  return {
    imgId: this.$route.params.Iid,
    title: "child",
  };
 },
};
</script>
```

This is not displaying image
----Main Component
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9saM.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jzJb.png)

---Child Component
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9ZF0.png)

This is displaying image(But I dont want to mention image details manually in object / array)
---Main Component
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tx1fo.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UZK5.png)

---Child Component
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWgB8.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIFjV.png)

Router index file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oc2uZ.png)

I tried calling images manually, it worked, but I want to call image into child componet which is clicked on parent component ( Images are dynamic)

Comment: What do you mean by - ***I want to call image into child component which is clicked on parent component*** ? You can pass the clicked image source into the child as a prop and then render that in a child component.

Comment: Is the `images` data available inside the child component?